# Cannot get elseif ASP to function

Tags: if-statement, vbscript, asp-classic

I have hit a problem with an `ElseIf` statement, hopefully someone might be able to help me. :)

This is the code we currently have:

```
<%
Response.Buffer = True
If Request.QueryString("MapLocation") = "" Then
    Response.Redirect "Page_Not_Found.html"
ElseIf Request.QueryString("StaffName") = "Shaun MaWhinney" Then
    Response.Redirect "Leavers.html"
Else
    strMapLocation = Request.QueryString("MapLocation")
    strStaffName = Request.QueryString("StaffName")
End If
%>
```

I added in the ElseIf statement hoping it would work, but unfortunately it completely skips it and executes the Else code. The StaffName definitely equals "Shaun MaWhinney" so I am lost as to why it doesn't open the leavers.html file. Any ideas? Your time reading this message is appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. Try replacing `Response.Redirect "Leavers.html"` with `Response.Write "StaffName Hit" : Response.End`; see if it gets printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two simple things you can try - first, have this as your else if clause

```
ElseIf Server.Urlencode(Request.QueryString("StaffName")) = "Shaun+MaWhinney" Then
Response.Redirect "Leavers.html"
```

Second

1. Remove your ElseIf clause
2. After End If add the following line

If strStaffName = "Shaun MaWhinney" then Response.Redirect "Leavers.html" End If

Obviously, you can also try Server.Urlencode with method 2

Comment: Thank you, this ElseIf statement helped me greatly! Thanks to everyone else for their time in helping me with this query. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple script

```
Option Explicit

Dim aCond : aCond = Array(False, True) ' <-- your experiments here

WScript.Echo Join(aCond)
If aCond(0) Then
   WScript.Echo 1
ElseIf aCond(1) Then
   WScript.Echo 2
Else
   WScript.Echo 3
End If
```

output:

```
cscript 21237966.vbs
False True
2
```

to convince yourself, that the ElseIf branch will be executed when

1. `Request.QueryString("MapLocation") = ""` is False
2. `Request.QueryString("StaffName") = "Shaun MaWhinney"` is True

and that the only way to get to the Else branch is to start with `aCond = Array(False, False)`. So double-check whether Shaun's last name is "MaWhinney" (or "MacWhinney" or "McWhinney").

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% sure that the name is correct / capitalized the same way you are testing (ie: "Shaun Mawhinney" is going to be different to "Shaun MaWhinney", etc). If you're not sure, you could convert and test the string in lowercase/uppercase.

If you are simply trying to redirect to `Leavers.html` when `MapLocation` is empty for Shaun MaWhinney, you could do this:

```
<%
Response.Buffer = True
If Request.QueryString("MapLocation") = "" Then
    If lcase(Request.QueryString("StaffName")) = "shaun mawhinney" Then
        Response.Redirect "Leavers.html"
    else
       Response.Redirect "Page_Not_Found.html"
    End If
Else
    strMapLocation = Request.QueryString("MapLocation")
    strStaffName = Request.QueryString("StaffName")
End If
%>
```